# How to tell a JavaScript formatter to add blank lines between function definitions?

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, code-formatting, blank-line

I have some JS files which I want to format nicer with a CLI formatter tool like [Prettier](https://prettier.io). I tried Prettier itself, but I was surprised to find that it doesn't add blank lines between function definitions. I think this would enhance visual structure significantly.

An example might clarify what I'm after. Given the input source code:

```
import {foo, bar} from "./myfoobar.js"
export var myfirstfunc = function (para) {
  ...
}
// mysecondfunc does wonderful things
export var mysecondfunc = function (more, para) {
  ...
}
```

I would like to see the following output code with blank lines:

```
import {foo, bar} from "./myfoobar.js"

export var myfirstfunc = function (para) {
  ...
}

// mysecondfunc does wonderful things
export var mysecondfunc = function (more, para) {
  ...
}
```

In my test Prettier doesn't do this. Is there a way to tell Prettier -- or another formatter -- to do this kind of visual structuring?

Comment: No ~ https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#empty-lines

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve something similar to this by using [ESLint's `padding-line-between-statements`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/padding-line-between-statements) rule. Any sort of STATEMENT_TYPE (such as `export`, `import`, `var`) can be specified to require a blank line between it and another given STATEMENT_TYPE (or wildcard, to match anything).

The following config:

```
padding-line-between-statements: [
    "error",
    { blankLine: "always", prev: "export", next: "*" },
    { blankLine: "always", prev: "import", next: "*" },
    { blankLine: "always", prev: "var", next: "*" },
]
```

results in automatically fixed code of:

```
import {foo, bar} from "./myfoobar.js"

export var myfirstfunc = function (para) {
}

// mysecondfunc does wonderful things
export var mysecondfunc = function (more, para) {
}
```

[Demo](https://eslint.org/demo#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)

Any IDE that supports ESLint's auto-fixing (such as VSCode) should be able to implement this.

Feel free to tweak with the config settings objects to require spaces between different types of statements as desired.

Comment: Interesting! Will try it out.

Comment: Sadly this also adds new lines after `export * from "./sth1"`. Some index files could have a bunch of this kind of export. Can we disable it for such cases and only add new lines in case of export func|type|var declaration?